# EntityFramework core error "value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the code as below

```
string[] hpoIdArr = {"HP:0000083", "HP:0000822"};
string sqlQry = "SELECT * FROM dbo.PatientHPO WHERE HPOId in ('" + string.Join("','", hpoIdArr) + "')";
patientIds = dbSet.FromSql(sqlQry)
            .GroupBy(x => x.PatientId)
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() == hpoIdArr.Length)
            .Select(grp => grp.Key)
            .ToArray();
```

The code run into an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range", but I don't understand what does that mean. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why your separator in Join is ','. Shouldn't it be just ,

Comment: That creates valid SQL, but why use `FromSql` for that? You can write `dbSet.Where(x => hpoIdArr.Contains(x.HPOId))`

Comment: Yes, that's right, dbSet.Where(x => hpoIdArr.Contains(x.HPOId)) is a better way. But I think that doesn't solve the problem. I thought my groupBy section is correct, but seems I was wrong...